# Lambda Function in python for my Purchase dataset

Tags: python, function, lambda, dataset

I have my data set where I have to fill the missing values in the Column "Extended Price" with a formula with other columns that is = Quantity Ordered * Unit Cost.
I have tried this function it works but keep changing for me the non missing values from their original values to 0 because of else part.

How do I keep the values for the non missing values and use the function only to make changes on the missing values.

Here is my code function.

```
df['Extended Cost'] = df.apply(lambda var: var['Quantity Ordered'] * var['Unit Cost'] if var['Extended Cost'] != var['Extended Cost'] else 0, axis=1)
```

Suggestions and help are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with a sample of your input data and expected output so that we can better understand your question. Assuming you're using pandas, see [How to make a good pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Also, under what circumstance would `if var['Extended Cost'] != var['Extended Cost']` be true? Isn't the value always equal to itself?

Comment: I want to perform the formula when var['Extended Cost'] is Null value. since this columns contains float values and other empty missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value equal to itself in the `else` case. that way you aren't changing the data if it exists.

Also your `if` condition should be around the other way around, i.e. do something if the value is None, else do nothing

```
df['Extended Cost'] = df.apply(lambda var: var['Quantity Ordered'] * var['Unit Cost'] if var['Extended Cost'] == None else var['Extended Cost'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot yes this is would much better